# GetParameter in Java returns error

Tags: java

I am editing source code with very limited knowledge of java (I use php/AS and I need this as well unfortunately).

Anyway, I am reading params from an HTML file. In one of the classes of the source it reads parameters just fine, but when I try to do it from another class it isn't working

```
String tmp;

tmp = getParameter("playername");
```

Here's the error message I get...

```
C:\java\applet\source2\BufferView.java:432: error: cannot find symbol
        tmp = getParameter("playername");
              ^
  symbol:   method getParameter(String)
  location: class BufferView
1 error
```

Comment: So, read it in, in the class where it _does_ work, and pass it in to the appropriate method in `BufferView`.

Comment: *"I use php/AS and I need this as well unfortunately"*  Wow!  Way to get the help of people who are proficient in Java..

Answer (score 2):

The `getParameter()` method is not defined within the `BufferView` class.

What you possibly need is a `HttpServletRequest` instance, from which you will be able to invoke the `getParameter()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`getParameter` is a method on the class where it works.  Your other class needs to provide an instance of that class to call the method.

[Try this.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565927186.do)